# JOLT spec to convert a nested JSON to a denormalized JSON

Tags: json, denormalization, jolt

Need Jolt spec for converting a nested JSON to a denormalized JSON.

**Input:**

```
{
   header :
     company: "ABC",
     ip: 10.3.2.4,
     network : [ {url:"http://abc.in", "latency":2000}, {url:"http://xzy.au", "latency":2000}],
}
```

**Output:**

```
[
{
  url:"http://abc.in",
   ip: 10.3.2.4
},
{
  url:"http://xzy.com",
   ip: 10.3.2.4
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "header": {
        "network": {
          "*": {
            "url": {
              "@": "[&2].url",
              "@(3,ip)": "[&2].ip"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```